# Play/pause audio element on playlist item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

So i´m working with this audio player http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/vkMqR/light/ , and what i´m triying to do is to "pause" a song when that item on the playlist is clicked. Be in consideration that im very new at this js stuff. can anyone help me? this is the code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('bl-content a');
    len = tracks.length; 0;
    audio[0].volume = .75;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks on an .active track in the playlist, you'll need do check if the track is playing or paused and then play or pause accordingly.

Something like:

```
if(audio.paused){
  //Audio is currently paused so play it
  audio.play();
}else{
  //Pause it
  audio.pause();
}
```

TutsPlus has a pretty good article describing the play control functions.  Find it here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081

Excerpt:

```
myaudio.play(); - This will play the music.
myaudio.pause(); - This will stop the music.
myaudio.duration; - Returns the length of the music track.
myaudio.currentTime = 0; - This will rewind the audio to the beginning.
myaudio.loop = true; - This will make the audio track loop.
myaudio.muted = true; - This will mute the track
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry, but i´ve tried to integrate this into my code and nothing´s changed. also, im not quite sure where to put it, or how, to get the job done.